# Does the British spouse for a UK Family Visa have to be living in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

On the UK Home Office webpage listing the [requirements](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse) for a spouse, it never specifies that the spouse must be currently living in the UK, only that the couple "intend to live together permanently in the UK after you apply".

However, on the Fees section of the page, the first row is the "Cost if **joining** your partner, parent or child" (emphasis mine). That possibly implies that the British spouse should be currently living in the UK.

I couldn't find clarification elsewhere on the HO website. One third-party website discussed a "present in the UK" clause (and claimed that as long as the couple do intend to both be in the UK that counts as "present"), but I can't find any "present" clause on the HO website (even it's archived recensions on the Wayback Machine).

So is just intent to live in the UK enough?; and the British spouse can be living outside the UK at present?